# How do I merge a master branch's changes into my side project branch in one git commit?

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, gerrit

I have a "project" branch that was created off of a "master" branch about a month ago. I'm trying to bring in all of the changes from the master branch into the project branch while still keeping the branches separate. I need an end result of a single commit that is a combination of the two branches that I can then push to our gerrit setup.

I've tried fetching the latest versions of both branches and then merging the master branch into the project branch. This resulted with a merge commit that joined the two branches. However, I want a single commit with all the changes that will play nicely with gerrit, so I tried rebasing the branch on top of "origin/project," but this then wanted me to go and merge the 600+ commits in the master branch since the two split. Since this is the case, I'm assuming pushing the commit at this point will result with gerrit requiring a crazy rebase as well.

I also tried rebasing and squashing the project branch on itself down to one commit above the point where it branched off, and then rebasing that one commit on top of the master branch. At the end it gave me a "Refs ref/heads/project is at [hash] but expected [different hash]" error. This approach also would erase the commit history of my project branch, wouldn't it?

Is there a better way to approach this? Am I correct in my assumption that as long as the master branch doesn't have any of the project stuff in it, the next time I try to combine the two, I'll have the same conflicts?

Comment: Kudos for clearly describing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A `merge` does not combine the two branches into one.  The are still two different physical branches in which commits go to two separate places.  Also the master branch will not have changes from project since the original split.  So merge is the way to go.  There is an option on `merge` called `--no-ff` that will force a separate commit.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think a merge commit wouldn't work?  Combining the history of two branches into a single commit is exactly what a merge intends to do.  They work fine with Gerrit - we use them all the time.